# Developing 3 related node modules; structuring for npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm

I'm developing a node package (`canto34`) I previously distributed as a single file, `canto34.js`.

The source has grown to have three modules in it, so now it contains three files I'd like to distribute;

- `canto34.js` -- the core
- `canto34-expect.js` -- tdd code relying on the core.
- `canto34-syntax.js` -- relies on the core and provides syntax highlighting.

Is it possible to bundle something to npm to supply three different modules (so that I could install it with a single package;

```
npm install canto34 --save-dev
```

and then include any of them like;

```
import * as canto34 from 'canto34'
import * as canto34Syntax from 'canto34-syntax'
import * as canto34Expect from 'canto34-expect'
```

If it's possible, what do you need to do in the `package.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

Specifically what you're asking: No that's not possible.
However, you could make a split export and do the following:

But keep in mind, this changes the way you access the module so you need to update your `Readme` and watch out with [semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning), you can't just call this a `patch`.

#### Module

```
module.exports = {
    main: canto34,
    syntax: canto34Syntax,
    expect: canto34Expect
}
```

#### App

```
import {main, syntax, expect} from 'canto34';
```